# Discuss about [windows] tag

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tags, retag-request

This is a [retag-request](/questions/tagged/retag-request).

From the tag wiki of the [windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows) tag, we see:

> **GENERAL WINDOWS SUPPORT IS OFF-TOPIC**. Support questions may be asked on https://superuser.com Windows is an operating system developed by Microsoft. Use this tag only if your question relates to using Windows APIs or Windows-specific behavior related to your code, **not just because you happen to run your code on Windows**.

From this tag description I came to the conclusion that this tag should be used **only** when the question is related to Windows APIs and if there is a **specific** behavior related to code. These two things *rarely happen*.

However, I can see lots of questions that are off-topic (general computing) and some others that are tagged [windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows) because the code is run in Windows.

Currently, there are ~130k questions tagged [windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows), ~6.2k of them are closed. A small test also, will show that questions tagged:

- [windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows) [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) are ~18k.
- [windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows) [batch-file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/batch-file) are ~12k.
- [windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows) [cmd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cmd) are ~6.4k.
- [windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows) [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) are ~6k.
- [windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows) [c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c) are ~6k.
- [windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows) [command-line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/command-line) are ~2.3k.

So, `130 - (18 + 12 + 6.4 + 6 + 6 + 2.3) = 130 - 50.7 = ~80k`.

Some additional cleanup may reduce questions to ~50k.

So, shall we do a, not so small, cleanup here?

Comment: You want to do a cleanup on ~80k questions? Oy veh. To what end? What problem will this solve? Are you having trouble finding relevant Windows programming questions to answer? I'm not, and that's literally my specialty.

Comment: Burninating the entire tag isn't a good idea. C and C++ both have Windows-specific APIs (`Windows.h` for one). Same with command line-stuff

Comment: This... feels like a [Quixotic quest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don_Quixote), nobel but fruitless in the bigger scheme of things. Just remove the tag when it clearly doesn’t add anything *when already editing the post for other ressons*.

Comment: If you are proposing a retag, tag this question with [retag-request], not [burninate-request]. If you really want to burninate, don't claim in the body that you didn't really mean it and that you just wanted a retag. If you just want to discuss the utility of the tag, then just tag [tags]. VTC'ing as *unclear* in the meantime.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> So, this tag should be used only when the question is related to Windows APIs and if there is a specific behavior related to code. These two things rarely happen.

There's already a [winapi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/winapi) tag. I'm not sure what you mean by "specific behavior related to code".

People use [windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows) for context, the same way the vast majority of the people using [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23) use it because they're writing C# code - not because their question concerns the nature of the C# language directly.

There's little to be gained (and potentially much to be lost) by stripping context from questions.

If you want to help clean this tag, I recommend focusing on question that are *blatantly* off-topic, stuff like this: [Choose Operating System for custom built pc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54498415/choose-operating-system-for-custom-built-pc) - note that I didn't remove the *tag*, I closed the *question*, since the *question* was the problem here...

Also, it appears that the tag wiki excerpt here gradually evolved away from a description of the tag's purpose / use and into a desperate plead with folks not to ask off-topic questions. While that's understandable, it also makes the excerpt useless for trying to actually determine what the tag is for... I've edited that.